# Unexpected syntax and parse error T_RETURN

Tags: php, syntax-error, parse-error

I have this function, and it returns `Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_RETURN`. I would appreciate you help me. Thanks.

```
function getPin(){
    return substr(str_shuffle('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ123456789123456789123456789'), 0, 6); ;
}
function validPin(){
    $pre = getPin();
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `images` WHERE `pin` = '$pre' ");
    $count = mysql_num_rows($sql);
    if($count > 0){
        return validPin();
    }else{
        return $pre;
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no syntax error with the above code. Your error is somewhere else.

Comment: Which line actually returns the error?

Comment: Actually, I noticed there's no error. This piece of code is actually from line 10 - 23 and it tells it's in line 11 (actually the ``return substr()...``) statement. @MikeBrant

Comment: @nickb please read my previous comment.

Comment: There might not be a closed bracket in earlier lines of code then. You should also clean up your double semicolon on line 11.

Comment: @MikeBrant that's the answer, actually I just needed to move the lines to one more but thanks for the semicolon detail. Answer so I give you your points

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might not be a closed bracket in earlier lines of code then. You should also clean up your double semicolon on line 11.